# Is MySQL Insert If Not Exists Query Thread Safe

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table in MySQL (which needs to be partitioned by `last_updated_date`). However I want the values in `col1` of the table to be unique (but since MySQL mandates the partitioned column to be included in each unique key constraint I cannot create a primary key on `col1` alone). Now I have this query to insert a record in the table

```
INSERT INTO TAB1 (col1, clo2, clo3) SELECT 'val1', 'val2', 'val3'
from dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from TAB1 where col1 = 'val1');
```

The above query will ensure the uniqueness of col1 in case of non paralell inserts. However I want to confirm if it will also ensure the uniqueness of `col1` in case of parallel inserts by 2 connections i.e. is the above query thread safe?

Note : I am using `InnoDB engine`.

Comment: No, I don't think it is thread safe.  The two threads could both run the `select` at the same time and then insert the same id.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a really good solution for what you want to do.  Including `col1` as the first partitioning key pretty much kills your reason for partitioning by `last_update_date`.

One kludge is do range partitioning with some absurdly wide range, so everything is really in one partition.  You can do this with [`range columns`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-columns-range.html).

```
partition by range columns (id, last_updated_date)
    partition p0 values less than (9999999999, '2015-01-01'),
    . . .
);
```

This then allows you to include the `unique` constraint.  The downside is that you need a comparison to the `id` in all your `where` clauses (`where id < 9999999999`).

Another approach is to make `id` an auto-incremented id.  In that case, you don't have to worry about duplicates.

Or, make the `id` unique within each partition, and use the query in your question.  This is not 100% sure, but the conditions for a collision are:

- 2+ insert threads are running
- duplicates might then go into adjacent partitions

The second requires a partition switch, which is quite rare, so the probability of a collision is quite low.

Answer (score 0):

Setup:  Have an index starting with `col1`.  (It is useless to make it `UNIQUE`, since you would have to add `last_updated_date` to it.)

```
BEGIN;
SELECT 1 from TAB1 where col1 = 'val1'  FOR UPDATE;
If you got 1, ROLLBACK and exit.
INSERT INTO TAB1 (col1, clo2, clo3) VALUES ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
COMMIT;
```

On another note... What benefit do you get from using PARTITION?